# How to use Digitech JamMan Solo XT with headphones?

Tags: effects-pedal, headphones

So, I bought mysef a the jamman solo xt looper pedal from digitech. Works fine, as expected when connected to the amp. When i plug it to headphones though, i have mono output (left ear only) which is really annoying. Due to my schedule, I only get to practice at night and the amp is out of the question. Is there any way i can get a stereo output from this pedal when using headphones without buying extra parts? If not, what would be the cheapest solution to achieve this? Thank you

Comment: I guess your amp doesn't have a headphone output?

Comment: Your guess is corect :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the issue with the following:

- 1 x RCA (2 outputs) to jack (female) - https://goo.gl/JiPi6c
- 2 x RCA to jack adapters - https://goo.gl/xy1K71

It works like charm and it was cheap too.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the jamman xt is a mono looper. Your headphones are likely stereo. The solution is to make your headphones mono. There are probably adapters that do this, but with a little experience in electronics, you could take a short male-to-female stereo cable and short the tip and ring (not the sleeve/ground). there are also headphone amps that you can buy that don't require any DIY.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no experience in electronics. I found this adapter though https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61baboailrL._SX355_.jpg which should work if the  output is stereo. However, I couldn't find it in local stores. I'll order it online and see how it goes. I've noticed that most pedals are mono, too bad I didn't check this specification before buying the pedal :).

Comment: @Gabi I think that adapter will only convert *two* mono signals into a stereo one, i.e. a Left-Right configuration. However a web search for "mono stereo adapter" did yield some interesting results, I'd myself go for one of those instead.

Comment: Thank you for the info. Unfortunately, I can't find anything locally :|. I've been to a music store and the guy said there's nothing I can do except using an amp with headphones output. I find it hard to believe there is no adapter for this situation...